# how predefined height of a div when its min-height is 100%

Tags: html, height, css

plz see the below html :

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body
        {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        #MainDiv
        {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="MainDiv">
        Contents - A Repeater That Will Grow From Code Behind
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

how can i have height -> 800px for MainDiv At Start(Low Content)?
and force it's height to increase when contents are growed!

thanks in advance

Comment: So much of CSS styling is creating the *illusion* of what you want. Try repeating a background down the entirety of `body`. Or use a `fixed` div that has 100% of the height of the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#MainDiv
{
    min-height: 800px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: it works - but there is a problem about html & body -> not grow!  how force them to grow too?

Comment: use "height: auto;" instead of "height: 100%"

Comment: thanks for comment / but by doing that i lose 100% height of body or html - i do n't want any scroll for my window at start(because of using predefine height for body or html)

Comment: I;m not sure I understand what you want :P If you set div height to 800 px and your screen resolution has less than 800px in height you will get a scroll bar anyway. If you dont want a scroll bar simply use: "overflow:hidden;". And if you want to have scroll only sometimes you need javascript.

Answer (score 1):

write like this

```
#MainDiv{
 min-height:800px;
}

EDIT:
```

Answer of your above comment

If you want `html & body 100%` height then just write like this

```
html, body{
  height:100%
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer / but in the question their height is 100% and they do n't grow with MainDiv!

Comment: This person has the right idea, just set html and body to have a min-height of 100% instead of a height of 100%.  That way it will take up the full screen at first, then it will grow with MainDiv.